# Use nested variables in Vuetify theme customisation

Tags: vue.js, material-design, vuetify.js, vue-cli-3

I want to use variables `--v-primary-link`, `--v-primary-text`, and `--v-primary-disabled`. But Vuetify is generating only `--v-primary-base` Is this possible using the code which is written below? Or Is there any other way to do this?

**code from @plugins/vuetify.js**

```
light: {
  primary: {
    base: '#ffc844',
    text: '#303030',
    link: '#FFA844',
    disabled: '#AAAAAA',
  },
}
```

Expected Output: It should also generate the variables `--v-primary-link`, `--v-primary-text`, and `--v-primary-disabled`

Comment: Why do you want to have this color variables inside the primary? Is `--v-secondary` ok for you? If so i can give you an example.
What you have at the moment is for color variations (lighten and darken)

Answer (score 0):

According to Vuetify's doc on customProperty theming [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/theme/#custom-theme-variants), there is a limited list of variables you can overwrite

```
{
  base: string
  lighten5: string
  lighten4: string
  lighten3: string
  lighten2: string
  lighten1: string
  darken1: string
  darken2: string
  darken3: string
  darken4: string
}
```

But you can create your own custom version

```js
// src/plugins/vuetify.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: {
          base: '#ffc844',
          text: '#303030',
          link: '#FFA844',
          disabled: '#AAAAAA',
       },
      },
    },
    options: {
      customProperties: true,
    },
  },
})
```

And use it in your css like so according to vuetify's [doc](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/theme/#custom-properties)

```html
<style scoped>
  .link {
    color: var(--v-primary-link);
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Your answer is **wrong**. We cannot have the object of custom property names. The  `customProperties: true,` means we can have a custom variable name on the level where you defined `primary` color. Like if will give support to use other variable names. Initially, the answer I asked has no solution RN.

Comment: Indeed. The concept around my answer only works with the already defined properties in vuetify. My bad